# Логин и пароль для VMBitrix7.4-3-CentOS7.7-x86_64

Tags: linux, windows, centos, виртуальная-машина, login

Какой логин и пароль надо ввести для ( ( https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php ) )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

?

Comment: Логин `root` и пароль по умолчанию `bitrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Примечание: Для суперпользователя root по умолчанию задан пароль bitrix.

Взял с официальной странички:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=2715